# How do I force Chrome to load a fresh copy of a page?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, redirection, browser-cache

I am developing a new website, and I originally had a Url redirect on the domain that took users to an existing site in order to avoid a parked domain notice showing up.  When it came to put the first version of the site up on the web, I removed the redirect and waited a good 48 hours (for the DNS to catch up with the change).  But even after this wait, every time I tried navigating to the domain, it redirected anyway.  I became suspicious that it might not be because the domain was redirecting, but because Chrome (my browser of choice) had the old routing cached.  I confirmed this was the case by running Edge on the domain -- it took me right to the new website.

It appears that I need to instruct Chrome to stop caching pages, and always check for a new version of the website.  The must be a way to do this.  Someone please tell me.  I am a fairly new Chrome user and don't know much about setting options in it.

I have looked in Options, but no setting there seems to be the equivalent of Internet Explorer's "get new copy of each page".  In fact, Edge doesn't seem to have it, either!!

Comment: Is CTRL + F5 what you're looking for? Alternatively, go to the networking tab in Developer Tools and click the disable caching box.

Comment: It also depends on the redirect you were using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301 vs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a similar question posted here:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/xR-6YAkcASQ

The answers are quite old so I don't know if it's been updated but back then it didn't look like chrome had an automated process (it probably still doesn't).

From the source above, two manual solutions are:

1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>DELETE</kbd> and manually clear the cache each time; or
2. You will need to add a `'?random.number'` or `"?date.code"` to every link each time a URL is pressed on your website.

For example, if  `'myhomepage.html?272772'` is stored in the cache, then by generating a new random number eg. `'myhomepage.html?2474789'`, Google Chrome will be forced to look for a new copy.

Sorry if this is no help!

Edit: A potentially even better solution if you are developing using the Chrome Development Tools is found at this source:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development

With a screenshot of the upvoted solution:

[image]

Hopefully this is an appropriate way to answer using another source.

Answer (score 3):

The other answer might be good for you own Chrome instance, but every other user will have the same problem.  The problem is that Chrome needs to have `must-revalidate` in the Cache-Control` header in order to re-check files to see if they need to be re-fetched.

To fix this once and for all for all users, include the following response header:

```
Cache-Control: must-validate
```

This tells Chrome to check with the server, and see if there is a newer file.  If there is a newer file, it will receive it in the response.  If not, it will receive a 304 response, and the assurance that the one in the cache is up to date.

If you do NOT set this header, then in the absence of any other settings that invalidate the file, Chrome will *never* check with the server to see if there is a newer version.

Here is a [blog post](https://agiletribe.wordpress.com/2018/01/29/caching-for-chrome/) that discusses the issue further.

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> to load a fresh copy of the website.

Otherwise, you can switch off the caching feature from the developers tool. To do so:

1. Visit the website and press <kbd>F12</kbd>.
2. Go to networks tab and check the box "Disable cache".

This way you can always force the website to load fresh content and not cached files.

Comment: SHIFT+F5 works perfectly here.

Answer (score 2):

I tried EVERYTHING. This is what finally worked:
Command prompt:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

THIS finally worked.

Answer (score 0):

On desktop, you can delete the cache for that website only via this

```
chrome://settings/siteData?searchSubpage=example.com
```

Replace example.com with your domain

[image: remove all cache]

Then you can either go to each relevant entry and hit the garbage icon, or just click "Remove All Shown" to get rid of everything matching the query