# Clear cache for a site in different browsers

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, browser, browser-cache

I need to test a site in different browsers. Clearing browser cache deletes cache for all sites.

How to clear or reset cache for a particular site in different browsers?

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1737251/394090 I hope this helps (for chrome)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Chrome / Edge

**Windows / Linux / Chrome OS**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + reload button
- Open Chrome dev tools by clicking <kbd>F12</kbd>. Right click Reload button. Then, click "Hard Reload" or "Empty Cache and Hard Reload".

**Mac**

- <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
- <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + reload button
- Open Chrome dev tools by clicking <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> + <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>. Then, right click Reload button. In drop-down menu click "Hard Reload" or "Empty Cache and Hard Reload".

### Firefox and related browsers

**Windows / Linux**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>

**Mac**

- <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
- <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + reload button

### Safari

- <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> + <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>

### Internet Explorer

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + reload button

### Opera

**Windows**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + reload button

**Mac**

- <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
- <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + reload button